# Manually serializing an ember-data model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an ember-data model that is using the EmbeddedRecordsMixin.

Using `model.save()` correctly serializes the payload including the embedded records.

I need to serialize the model manually into a javascript object.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it :p

```
model.serialize()
```